# Implementing and using MSR service layer using CCO's in POS application

Tags: c++, mfc, com, atl

I am trying to create OPOS Service layer for MSR POS Application, that would allowed us to use the functionality of MSR through OPOS Control object.

So far, I had implemented OPOS Service layer for MSR using Atl component and I am trying to call ActiveX Object(.ocx) using CCO's of MSR in my Service layer.

My questions are:
1. I am trying to add ActiveX Object(.ocx) of CCO's of MSR in Service object in VS2017
    Tools-> Choose Toolbox Items...-> COM Components -> Browse... -> OK

It gives an error like "make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .net framework version" even I had compiled Control object and Service object in same Windows 10 .net framework. 
[Screenshot of error which I got after adding ocx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvAC0.jpg)

I had gone through many forum's related to this error but those are not helpful.

2. Are we doing the right thing? If this is not the right way to use CCO's in Service layer, so can anyone help me to do this in a right way in my project.

Note: I am not using "POS for .Net", I am using "POS for C++".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Although a bit old, this project will be helpful. [RichardChambers/atl_msr_so](https://github.com/RichardChambers/atl_msr_so)

Comment: Also, this article will be helpful. [Writing an OPOS Service Object using ATL](http://dhanushkadangampola.blogspot.com/2015/03/writing-opos-service-object-using-atl.html)